# WebStorm import statement autocomplete

Tags: dart, webstorm

I miss the possibility to auto-complete the import statements in Dart files. How to enable those in WebStorm?

Similar functionality was available in DartEditor before it was discontinues and it allowed to type 'package:| and listed all available packages.

Comment: Works for me without any special configuration. What version of Dart and WebStorm are you using?

Comment: latest available - downloaded dart-sdk from dartlang.org and webstorm from their web site. Even when I type wrong import path it does not highlight it as error. I had to fire up darteditor to fix this and then go back to webstorm.

Comment: Should work out of the box. Do you have Dart Analysis tool window in WebStorm (this is to check that Dart Analysis Server works)? Screenshots illustrating the problem and showing project structure and configuration will help.

Comment: I have moved to a new linux system and now it works out of the box indeed, maybe something with my installation was wrong. Thanks